# Why first-stage regulator needs spring?

Tags: pressure, spring

[image: 1]

I'm wondering why first-stage pressure regulator for scuba divers on picture needs spring? Without spring, regulator valve seat should open as well when pressure in left-hand side lowers (breathing) and should close when pressure in left-hand side match the ambient pressure (gas flow from right-hand side). Am I right?

In that case, only purpose of spring that I can think of, is that we don't want pressure in left-hand side to be equal ambient pressure or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You want the medium pressure to be above the ambient pressure to provide a good flow to the secondary valve.  Without the spring, the primary valve would only open if the medium pressure were lower than the ambient.

Comment: So the reason why medium need to be at higher pressure than ambient, is that the second stage operates with resp. to ambient pressure ? In that case the regulator without spring should operate as well without second-stage. I mean sucking gas directly from output on the picture. And than breathing out  directly to water ....or something like that. I´m right ?

Comment: As I recall, the original aqualung did use a single stage regulator.  The two stage is less clumsy and perhaps safer.